# python 2.7 on windows 10 with zipline

Tags: python, python-2.7, zipline

What is the best way to install python 2.7 on windows 10 with zipline for stock trading  I have downloaded it several way and I can not get zipline to work. I have tried for 14 days and I finally crashed my mbr and had to do a reinstall of windows 10 and I have parts of python all over my computer.  I can clean it all out and start over, but where and how?

Comment: Have you tried via here? http://www.zipline.io/install.html#conda

Comment: I did, I installed anaconda, conda, micoconda I tried 3.5 2.7 and I could never get to all work together.  I removed 3.5 completely and scrubbed the register and all of the installs and directories. Then installed python 2.7 and started all over.  I was uninstalling when I got a windows update and I though it was a virus and shut down and destroyed my mbr.  Well I am back and want to try again to load 2.7 and zipline. Just not sure of the best way to get a completion.